# How to limit an SQL query to return at most one of something?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I have a table in my database representing releases of software; the relevant columns of the schema being as follows:

```
ProductID   int
PlatformID  tinyint
Date        datetime
```

All are not null, and there is also a unique key assigned to the first two columns.

I would like to build a query (using LINQ) which returns the latest release (e.g. Date) for each platform (PlatformID), **but no more than one record per platform (PlatformID)**, and is sorted by Date descending.

How can I do this?

---

EDIT: Here is the solution I used:

```
var product = ...;

var latestReleases = product.Releases
    .GroupBy(p => p.PlatformID)
    .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(p => p.Date).FirstOrDefault())
    .OrderByDescending(release => release.Date)
```

for clarity...

```
foreach (var release in latestReleases)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The latest release of MyProduct for {0} is {1}.",
        release.PlatformID, // of course this would be a string in real code ;)
        release.Version);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following code does what you’re asking for:

```
var latestProducts = db.Releases
    .GroupBy(p => p.PlatformID)
    .Select(grp => new {
        Platform = grp.Key,
        Latest = grp.OrderByDescending(p => p.Date).FirstOrDefault()
    })
    .OrderByDescending(entry => entry.Latest.Date);

foreach (var entry in latestProducts)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The latest product for platform {0} is {1}.",
        entry.Platform,
        entry.Latest.ProductID);
}
```

Here’s how it works:

- First, take all the products
- Group them into groups by common PlatformID
- Within each group, sort the products in that group by date descending and pick the first (that’ll be the one with the latest date)
- For each group, create an object containing the PlatformID and the platform’s latest Product
- Sort this list of objects by date descending.

Comment: Timwi, thanks very much for your help. While your answer wasn't entirely correct (I think you are trying to get the most recently released product for platform X, whereas I wanted the most recent release of product X for each platform), I have still accepted it as I was able to use it as the basis for the code I used which is in my above post. Come to think of it, your code could be useful for an advertisement... "Check out our latest release for <platform>!" ;)

Comment: @Jake Petroules: Thanks. By and large my code is correct; I just couldn’t have known about your schema structure surrounding products and releases. Your question didn’t state it. So I assumed there was a single `Products` table containing all the releases.

Comment: Yes, I should have been a little more specific, sorry. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
                from plat in 
                (
                    from p in Products
                    group p by p.PlatformID
                )

                let latestRelease = 
                (
                    from p in plat
                    orderby p.Date descending
                    select p
                ).FirstOrDefault()

                where latestRelease != null

                select new 
                {
                    PlatformID = plat.Key,
                    LatestProductID = latestRelease.ProductID,
                    LatestDate = latestRelease.Date
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

One line code:

```
IEnumerable<Product> products = AllProducts.GroupBy(p => p.PlatformID, 
    (pid, source) => source.Where(p => p.PlatformID == pid).OrderByDescending(p => p.Date).FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Well, I think it's really not so hard to read if you are familiar with this overload method.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using LINQ to Entities, LINQ to SQL, etc, then just use `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()`, they will be smart enough to limit the query to 1. If you prefer to be more explicit, you can add `Take(1)` to your query.

Comment: although true, doesn't address the actual question