# How can I write an SQL version of this LINQ query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

As shown at: [How to limit an SQL query to return at most one of something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473509/how-to-limit-an-sql-query-to-return-at-most-one-of-something)

I have the following tables:

Platforms

- PlatformID
- Name

Products

- ProductID
- Name

Releases

- ID
- ProductID
- PlatformID
- Version
- ReleaseDate

The releases table stores each release of a software product for a particular platform. I want to write a query to return the latest release of each product for each platform in the Releases table. I.E. If I release product X version 2.0 on platforms A, B and C, there will be 3 records in the Releases table:

- one for product X version 2.0 on platform A released on 2010-11-17
- one for product X version 2.0 on platform B released on 2010-11-17
- one for product X version 2.0 on platform C released on 2010-11-17

So, given a product ID, how do I obtain this information? I tried using GROUP BY like the LINQ solution I used but apparently I can't translate LINQ to SQL as well as .NET can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pedantic:

```
Select
  PR.Name,
  PL.Name,
  REL.Version,
  REL.ReleaseDate
From
  Releases As REL
  Inner Join Products As PR
    On REL.ProductID = PR.ProductID
  Inner Join Platforms As PL
    On REL.PlatformID = PL.PlatformID
Where
  REL.ID = (Select Top 1 Latest.ID
            From Releases As Latest
            Where Latest.PlatformID = REL.PlatformID
              And Latest.ProductID = REL.ProductID
            Order By Latest.ReleaseDate Desc)
```

Should also work (assuming you never decrease versions):

```
Select
  PR.Name,
  PL.Name,
  Max(REL.Version),
  Max(REL.ReleaseDate)
From
  Releases As REL
  Inner Join Products As PR
    On REL.ProductID = PR.ProductID
  Inner Join Platforms As PL
    On REL.PlatformID = PL.PlatformID
Group By
  PR.Name,
  PL.Name
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the first solution was perfect. The second one wouldn't have been suitable since I use `Major.Minor.Maintenance.Build` syntax for versions so I don't think `MAX()` would've handled that correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Did you know LINQ's DataContext class has a [Log property](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2007/08/17/DataContextLogLoggingLINQToSQLOutputConsoleDebuggerOuputWindow.aspx)?

Since you already have a LINQ query, why not peek behind the curtain? :-)